# How to make a GUI for bash scripts?

Tags: user-interface, bash, gtk, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to make some graphical dialogs for my script but don't know how.
I hear something about GTK-Server or something like that.
If someone knows how to link Bash with tcl/tk I also be satisfied.

Please do not post something like "change to C++" because my project
must be a script in Bash; there are no other options.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
Thanks for answers but I don't want "graphics" as in colors in the console, but graphical windows which I can move, minimize etc.
I will test `xmessage`, but I don't think that will be what I am searching for.

**EDIT 2:**
I don't want make a simple dialog like yes/no, but some interface like progress bars and buttons, something like a game.

Comment: You definitely want `zenity`.

Comment: In the old days there was "dtksh" a ksh-93 implementation with access to  Motif  libraries. You could set shell function callbacks and make a full graphical application with a shell scripts. It featured dialog, button, textbox, radio-button,...

Comment: Have a look at [`tkbash`.](https://github.com/phil294/tkbash)

Comment: the question is 8 years old.

Comment: unclosed dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354482/dialog-from-bash-script

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Before actually using GUI dialogues, consider using console prompts. Quite often you can get away with simple "y/n?" prompts, which in bash you achieve via the [`read` command](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/read/)..

```
read -p "Do something? ";
if [ $REPLY == "y" ]; then
    echo yay;
fi
```

If console prompt's just won't cut it, [Zenity](http://freshmeat.net/projects/zenity) is really [easy to use](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/), for example:

```
      zenity --error --text="Testing..."
      zenity --question --text="Continue?"
```

This only works on Linux/Gnome (or rather, it'll only be installed by default on such systems). The `read` method will work on pretty much any platform (including headless machines, or via SSH)

If you need anything more complex than what read or Zenity provides, "change to C++" is really the best method (although I'd recommend Python/Ruby over C++ for such shell-script-replacement tasks)

> I want to do simple interface for some strange game, the progress bar for health or something is the example for what I want. Variable "HEALTH" is 34, so make progress bar filled in 34/100

As a command-line script, it'd use Python:

```
$ export HEALTH=34
$ python -c "import os; print '*' * int(os.environ.get('HEALTH', 0))"
**********************************
```

Or to normalise the values between 1 and 78 (so you don't get line-wrapping on a standard terminal size):

```
$ python -c "import os; print '*' * int((int(os.environ.get('HEALTH', 0)) / 100.0) * 78)"
```

Zenity also has a [Progress Dialog](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/progress.html.en),

```
#!/bin/sh
(
echo "10" ; sleep 1
echo "# Updating mail logs" ; sleep 1
echo "20" ; sleep 1
echo "# Resetting cron jobs" ; sleep 1
echo "50" ; sleep 1
echo "This line will just be ignored" ; sleep 1
echo "75" ; sleep 1
echo "# Rebooting system" ; sleep 1
echo "100" ; sleep 1
) |
zenity --progress \
  --title="Update System Logs" \
  --text="Scanning mail logs..." \
  --percentage=0

if [ "$?" = -1 ] ; then
        zenity --error \
          --text="Update canceled."
fi
```

As I said before, if Zenity cannot do what you need, look into writing your game-thing as a "proper" script in Python/Ruby/Perl/C++/etc as it sounds like you're pushing the bounds of what a shell-script can do..

Comment: I don't want the yes/no, but I want to do simple interface for some strange game, the progress bar for health or something is the example for what I want.
Variable "HEALTH" is 34, so make progress bar filled in 34/100.
That I want to do.

Comment: The [Progress Dialog](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/progress.html.en) link above is broken :(

Comment: *So* easy to use: `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /users/zenity/stable/ on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at help.gnome.org Port 80`

Answer (score 25):

If you want to write a graphical UI in bash, [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/) is the way to go. This is what you can do with it:

```
Application Options:
  --calendar                                     Display calendar dialog
  --entry                                        Display text entry dialog
  --error                                        Display error dialog
  --info                                         Display info dialog
  --file-selection                               Display file selection dialog
  --list                                         Display list dialog
  --notification                                 Display notification
  --progress                                     Display progress indication dialog
  --question                                     Display question dialog
  --warning                                      Display warning dialog
  --scale                                        Display scale dialog
  --text-info                                    Display text information dialog
```

Combining these widgets you can create pretty usable GUIs. Of course, it's not as flexible as a toolkit integrated into a programming language, but in some cases it's really useful.

Comment: Except the manual is useless: https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/

Answer (score 16):

there is a command called `dialog` which uses the ncurses library. "*Dialog is a program that will let you to present a variety of questions or display messages using dialog boxes  from  a  shell  script.   These types  of  dialog boxes are implemented (though not all are necessarily compiled into dialog)*"

see http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/dialog

Comment: Funny enough, I was just installing a version of the utility when I cam across your answer. Dialog works quite well I think.

Comment: In addition to the `dialog` utility, `whiptail` should also be mentioned. They even maintain some level of compatibility between each other.

Answer (score 14):

Well, if you can use Tcl/Tk in your environment, you probably should write a TCL script and use that.  You might also look at [wish](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2364).

Comment: but that is not bash

Comment: It might not be bash, but there's a limit beyond which bash gets really awkward and doing GUIs of any complexity is well beyond that.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) that is [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) based or [whiptail](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/whiptail.1.html) that is [slang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang) based.

I think both have GTK or Tcl/Tk bindings.

Answer (score 7):

You can [gtk-server](http://www.gtk-server.org/) for this. Gtk-server is a program that runs in background and provides text-based interface to allow other programs (including bash scripts) to control it. It has examples for Bash (http://www.gtk-server.org/demo-ipc.bash.txt, http://www.gtk-server.org/demo-fifo.bash.txt)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Unfortunately, there don't seem to be .deb packages for it. Will try to compile it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Please, take a look at my library:
http://sites.google.com/site/easybashgui

It is intended to handle, with the same commands set, indifferently all four big tools "kdialog", "Xdialog", "cdialog" and "zenity", depending if X is running or not, if D.E. is KDE or Gnome or other. There are 15 different functions ( among them there are two called "progress" and "adjust" )...

Bye
:-)

Comment: cool, so it is an adapter.  Are the supported tools required or you lib will use whatever it find, compatibly with the environment detected?

Comment: This one is pretty cool actually. The bash programmer need not worry about which platform the user will be using KDE or gnome; it will automatically detect the environment and show the UI accordingly using the available libraries.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Qt/KDE installed, you can use [kdialog](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Shell_Scripting_with_KDE_Dialogs), which pops up a Qt dialog window.  You can easily specify to display a Yes/No dialog, OK/Cancel, simple text input, password input etc.  You then have access to the return values from these dialogs at the shell.