# GUI Using Shell Batch File

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm now going to develop a program that will generate Shell Batch Files(*.sh), but I want to know some things:

- It's possible to show GUIs using they?

  - How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked before:

[How to make a GUI for bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928019/how-to-do-gui-for-bash-scripts)

Summary of options:

- dialog
- Zenity
- use a different scripting language like Perl, Python, Ruby, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Gnome dialog may be of use [Gnome Dialog Util](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libgnomeui/stable/libgnomeui-gnome-dialog-util.html)
KDE has Kdialog [Shell Scripting with KDE Dialogs](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Shell_Scripting_with_KDE_Dialogs)