# Dialog from bash script

Tags: bash, user-interface, dialog

I want create a simple graphical (Qt, Gtk, ...) dialog, concretly a simple print dialog, as a "frontend" to lpr, in bash.
What I want? How many pages per page, printing interval. It's (at least) two options.

What is the best util(s) to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've searched what dialog creators are. I found [yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) and with this I can set my desired options:

```
yad --skip-taskbar --center --title="Print dialog" {--image,--window-icon}=/usr/share/icons/Tango/72x72/devices/printer1.png --form --item-separator=, --field="Pages per sheet":CB 1,2,4,6,8 --field="Pages"
```

[image: Dialog]

And when I choose "2 pages per sheet" and pages "1-12" and after click `OK` the output will `2|1-12|`.

This is what I desired. Zenity or Xdialog can do similar?

Answer (score 24):

There is

- [dialog](http://hightek.org/dialog/) (ncurses based)
- [xdialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/) (X11 based)

Other implementations are reported to exist:

- [zenity](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) (Gnome)
- [kdialog](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Shell_Scripting_with_KDE_Dialogs) (Kde)

If you use [`gpm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPM_%28software%29), you can even use the mouse in a console environment. It requires a tty, so it *will* work over ssh, screen, xterm etc. but not when piping/redirecting.

Both sport more or less the same interface so you can switch depending on whether an X display is available

Here is a dialog script that displays a simple YES/NO box:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIALOG=${DIALOG=dialog}

$DIALOG --title " My first dialog" --clear \
        --yesno "Hello , this is my first dialog program" 10 30

case $? in
  0)
    echo "Yes chosen.";;
  1)
    echo "No chosen.";;
  255)
    echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
```

[image]

Replacing `dialog` by `xdialog`:

[image]

Comment: See also `zenity` and `kdialog`.

Comment: @choroba - ooh my knowledge was dated; I don't use this very often :) Adding those

Comment: I know about these, but I don't know how can I put more than one item to dialog box, e.g. a `yesno` and an `inputbox` and a `fselect`. Or is this impossible?

Comment: @uzsolt: if you'd be so kind as to click on those links - every single one (**edit** except perhaps `dialog`) of them contains 'advanced' examples. However, if you really wanted to do 'complicated' dialgos, I suggest you **a.** use builtin guis from `lpr` and `cups` **b.** write in python/perl/etc

Comment: @sehe I've checked Xdialog's homepage before I've asked this question but I didn't found "advanced" examples. Now checked again, zenity and kdialog too but again not found. Or am I blind? :)

Comment: @sehe hm, is there exist complete dialog boxes to print? Like xpp? http://cups.sourceforge.net/xpp/

Comment: @uzsolt: since many applications use the stock dialogs, I'd suggest it is easy to use them. Perhaps you need to configure `lpr` to use them? In that case, however, it will not be easy to read the user's choice (except by writing a cups preprocessing filter, perhaps)

Comment: @sehe Yes, I want that receive the data/options from dialog and create the proper `lpr` command: `lpr -o page-ranges=Pages -o number-up=HowManyPagesPerSheet ...`

Answer (score 3):

### Whiptail displays user-friendly dialog boxes from shell scripts

[Whiptail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) is a `dialog` replacement using [newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29) instead of ncurses. It
provides a method for displaying several different types of dialogue boxes
from shell scripts. This allows a script developer to interact with
the user in a much friendlier manner.

[image: whiptail example]

Answer (score 1):

[`matedialog`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/matedialog.1.html) (AKA `mate-dialog`) uses GTK+.  It may also be the only script GUI dialog tool available under [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I strive to give my 2 cents.
There is also [guish](https://codeberg.org/phranz/guish) you could try, though experimental.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gdialog` in `gnome/ubuntu`. I can't find `xdialog` anymore in 14.10. The answer from @sehe works with it just change dialog for `gdialog`.

Comment: `apt-get install xdialog`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a pure-Bash graphical dialogue then [`ctypes`](https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh) has an example of [GTK+ dialogue generation](https://github.com/taviso/ctypes.sh/blob/master/test/gtk.sh).  In theory it should be able to call any GUI library installed or shipped alongside the script.  As of October 2020 it looks to be actively maintained.