# Bash script with graphical menus

Tags: bash, shell, menu

I have been writing simple bash scripts for a while now, and I was wondering how I could implement simple menus and, if possible, use menus with color.

In the past, I have written simple C applications that use [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) and would like to (if possible) have menus in my bash script where the user can use the up/down arrows to select items in a list, and go back/forth through a series of yes/no/cancel prompts.

I am familiar with setting up colored text in bash, so there's a start (eg: [bash using colors](http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html)), so the only requirement left at this point is to see if bash has these capabilities. I would prefer to avoid having to code an application in C/C++ for this, as I would like to be able to edit it on the fly.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354482/dialog-from-bash-script

Answer (score 30, accepted):

there is a package called [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/#documentation), is this relevant to your requirement?

Comment: `dialog` link is broken

Answer (score 9):

I haven't used this myself, but have you checked out [bashsimplecurses](https://github.com/metal3d/bashsimplecurses)? From the documentation, it looks like a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package I call [BashGuiHelper](https://github.com/dholstei/BashGuiHelper), besides all the standard tasks, it's has awesome tree handling/selections and can be compiled with static FLTK libs or a smaller SO-based version.