# Bash Script, move one element in a list

Tags: bash, arraylist

I'm trying to do a similar menu to the selection of boot devices in boot. If we have for example:

- apple
- orange
- strawberry
- banana

Then, select one of them with "space bar" (or whatever) and up or down the word in the list, using the UP and DOWN arrow keys. 
If we select strawberry hitting space bar and arrow Up 2 times the list will be:

- strawberry
- apple
- orange
- banana

An the last thing, is it possible to do that using dialog?, and can `t find any clue ... 
Sorry for my English and thank you ...

Comment: Question already answered, try **dialog** 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576401/bash-script-with-graphical-menus

Answer (score 0):

With plain bash you can only display the choices and ask the user to enter the desired choice.

Like command line installers (apt-get, zypper, yum ...).

For full screen menus you need some tool, like a binding to curses, or [dialog](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialog --menu`, from the `dialog` package which is often installed by default:

```
selection=$(dialog --stdout  --menu  "Pick something" -1 -1 10 \
    "1" "foo" "2" "bar")

echo "You selected: $selection"
```