# Message box in Linux (out of the box)

Tags: python, linux, blender, messagebox

I'm working on a addon for Blender using Python that need to ask some confirmation by the user.
I already did a working code for Windows, something like this:

```
from ctypes import *

user32 = windll.user32
Answer = user32.MessageBoxW(None, 'some question here', 'title', 4 | 0x40)

if Answer==6:
    print('You choose YES')
else:
    print('You choose NO')
```

Unfortunately (and obviously), it doesn't work in Linux.
I read about using **Tkinter** could be a solution but it isn't already installed on Linux and I prefer to use a solution that doesn't need to install packages before.

Someone colud suggest a Linux (or cross-platform) solution?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity call it with subprocess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialog from bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354482/dialog-from-bash-script) (read all the answers).

Comment: As I already wrote, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need to install packages before.

Answer (score 1):

A default install of blender does not include the entire default build of python. A list of python modules (that includes tkinter) are excluded when packaging a version of blender for distribution. You can find the exact list [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/creator/CMakeLists.txt$534). You may be interested in some of the window manager methods available like `invoke_props_dialog` used in [this example](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#dialog-box), but in general these won't be they way you should go.

There two common ways to go about getting variable input from a user. The first is a property that can be adjusted by the user as they choose, that is then used when your script is run. The other way is through operator properties.

Properties can [be added](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#assigning-to-existing-classes) to some existing classes and displayed in [panels](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html) for the user to edit.

Actions that are performed in blender such as when a user presses some keys, clicks a button or selects a menu item, are performed by operators. It is common for an operator to have properties that alter the result of it's action. For example when you add a UV Sphere and press <kbd>F6</kbd> you can adjust how much geometry the sphere has as well as it's size and location. These properties are also available at the bottom of the toolshelf region.

[image: uvsphere options]

As shown in [this example](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html#bringing-it-all-together), you can add properties to your operator's class and these properties can be adjusted by the user the same as in the UV Sphere example. You can also specify values to use when you place a button for the user to click -

```
def draw(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()
    row.operator('object.example_operator', text='go with 6').choice = 6
```